# Changing foregound color of menu item (action button) android

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-menu

In my Android application, I'd like to change the color of the buttons in my Actionbar. From what I have seen in other posts, I should add a style for this, but I cannot get it to work. It MIGHT also be due to the fact that the solutions I have seen is to change the text color - but I have icons with images (drawables). These images are Android's standard drawables - for example `android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"` that I should be able to change color of in some way.

[image]

This is the code for my very simple theme:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/my_green</item>
        <item name="background">@color/my_green</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In earlier posts, they suggest adding this line: `<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/your_color</item>` but it doesn't have any effect here. (probably since it's not text)

Grateful for your help!

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use icons with correct color in your resources but want to tint them at runtime?

Comment: I think that the thing is that I do. They are white, I want them to be white, but they look like they are transparent.

Comment: @Joakim.Ahle, I doubt that Android applies any coloring to them by default, so check that the drawables you provide don't have any alpha, e.g. they're #FFFF

Comment: As I said, these drawables are part of Android's library, I cannot change them anyway

Comment: But yes, they are actually transparent...

Comment: @Joakim.Ahle, Using default drawables is usually problematic, since they look different on different OS versions and different devices, which is probably not what you want. I'd suggest you provide your own drawables, which you can color in white and be sure they're displayed properly.

Comment: Yup, will have to do that, thanks.